# Baking light in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, lighting

How to bake light in cycles for an emessive map? I only need to bake the texture that highlights the mesh with light

Comment: you are talking about "the texture that highlights the mesh with light", could you please tell a bit more?

Comment: An annotated screenshot could help.